# Duplicates in Arraylist, comparing various fields java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a code to return an arrayList with the duplicates of an ArrayList
but seems it's not working, I am comparing all items in the array...

```
public ArrayList<ObjectList> duplicates(ArrayList<ObjectList> someObjectsList) {

    ArrayList<ObjectList> ret = new ArrayList<ObjectList>();
    for ( ObjectList aSomeObjectsList: someObjectsList) {

        String field1 = aSomeObjectsList.get1();
        String field2 = aSomeObjectsList.get2();
        String field3 = aSomeObjectsList.get3();
        String field4 = aSomeObjectsList.get4();
        for (ObjectList someObject : ret) {
            if (
                field1.trim().equals(someObject.get1())&& 
                field2.trim().equals(someObject.get2())&&
                field3.trim().equals(someObject.get3())&&
                field4.trim().equals(someObject.get4())     
                ){
                ret.add(aSomeObjectsList);

            }
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

But i guess I am doing something wrong because it doesn't return anything, and I know it has duplictates under this 4 field criteria

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do this. I have defined a basic class `ObjectList` that shows a way to implement `equals` and `hashCode`. Note that this assumes that all the internal variables are non-null. If these variables can contain null then you will need to check for that when computing the equals/hashCode. Also, the objects in this class must also themselves properly implement equals/hashCode.

```
public class ObjectList {

    private int h;

    private Object obj1;
    private Object obj2;
    private Object obj3;
    private Object obj4;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof ObjectList))
            return false;

        final ObjectList that = (ObjectList) o;
        return that.obj1.equals(obj1) && that.obj2.equals(obj2)
            && that.obj3.equals(obj3) && that.obj4.equals(obj4);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // caches the hashcode since it could be costly to recompute every time
        // but this assumes that your object is essentially immutable 
        // (which it should be if you are using equals/hashCode. If this is not
        // true and you want to just temporarily use this when doing the duplicate
        // test, move the h variable definition from the object level to this method
        // and remove this if statement.
        if (h != 0)
            return h;

        h = obj1.hashCode();
        h = h * 31 + obj2.hashCode();
        h = h * 31 + obj3.hashCode();
        h = h * 31 + obj4.hashCode();
        return h;
    }

}

public Collection<ObjectList> duplicates(
        final Collection<ObjectList> someObjectsList) {

    final Set<ObjectList> unique = new HashSet<ObjectList>(someObjectsList);
    final ArrayList<ObjectList> ret = new ArrayList<ObjectList>(someObjectsList);
    for (final ObjectList o : unique) {
        ret.remove(o);
    }

    // The ret list now contains the duplicate instances; instances 
    // with more than two occurrences will occur multiple times still in
    // this list.
    return ret;

    // If you want a list of unique duplicate instances then, comment out the above
    // return and uncomment this one.
    // return new HashSet<ObjectList>(ret);
}
```

Using `Collection<ObjectList>` is better, if you can do that, for both the parameter and returned value so you can vary the implementations (ArrayList, Set, etc).

Comment: Thanks I am doing this implementation and seems to work correctly, Also I know that I miss a lot of syntaxis of the language and a lot of its features, thanks Kevin

Answer (score 3):

```
    for (Object someObject : ret) {
        if (
            field1.trim().equals(someObject.get1())&& 
            field2.trim().equals(someObject.get2())&&
            field3.trim().equals(someObject.get3())&&
            field4.trim().equals(someObject.get4())     
            ){
            ret.add(aSomeObjectsList);

        }
    }
```

The above loop wouldn't work, since it has the size of zero.

Here you go,

```
public Set<ObjectList> duplicates(ArrayList<ObjectList> someObjectsList) {

    Set<ObjectList> originals = new HashSet<ObjectList>();
    Set<ObjectList> duplicates = new HashSet<ObjectList>();

    for ( ObjectList aSomeObjectsList: someObjectsList) {
        boolean added = originals.add(aSomeObjectsList);
        if(!added){
            duplicates.add(aSomeObjectsList);
        }     
    }
    return duplicates;
}
```

This would work, provided your `ObjectList` class have the correct implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

**Disclaimer:** This implementation will not provide the information about how many times a particular object was duplicated in the provided list. It will just tell you that a particular object was duplicated. I assumed that that was your real intention. If you wanna count, how many times, you have to modify the code accordingly.

**Hint/Suggestion:** You should override the `equals()` method and place your field equality check in there instead, once and for all.

Comment: how do I provide the ObjectList class hashcode() and equals() I still dont get it.
Do I have to create an interface? 

public class ObjectList implements Comparator<Object>{}  etc...?????
THANKS

Comment: No, just override `equals()` and `hashcode()` method. No need to `extend` or `implement` anything. Look at the example here, http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28 . And please try to learn and understand the language and its features. Grab a nice book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't compile - if `aSomeObjectsList` is an `Object` then it doesn't have methods `get1()`, `get2()`, etc.

Your logic won't work because you aren't checking each element in your input `List` against the other elements in the input `List`; rather, you're trying to check the return `List`.

Also, this is not a really efficient way to check for duplicates in a collection.  A better way would be to use a `HashMap`, where you could check set membership in roughly constant time.  If you have to use a `List`, then sort it first (assuming your objects have a natural ordering) and check adjacent members for equality.

Barring those two, just use `List.contains()`.

Comment: True as well :). Didn't notice.